# Unbiased Variance Estimator for Stratified Two Phase Simple Random Sampling without Replacement

Tags: sampling, sampling-theory

In the context of two-phase sampling for stratification (see [Särndall's Model Assisted Survey Sampling](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387406206) pg 350), in the particular case in which we use simple random sampling without replacement (srswor) in each phase, we can check with no issue that the variance of the $\widehat{Y}_U^{\text{strHT}^*}$ estimator is given by
\begin{equation}
V=KS_{yU}^2+V_2\text{, }
\end{equation}
where $S_{yU}^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{k\in U}(y_k-\bar{y_U})^2$, $K$ is a constant that we don't care about. We may also ignore $V_2$.

We want to find and unbiased estimator $\widehat{V}$ for $V$, and in order to do that, we proceed by finding an unbiased estimator for each term of the sum, which we can easily do for $V_2$, but not for $S_{yU}^2$.

Note that, for $X$ to be unbiased for $S_{yU}^2$ we have to prove that
\begin{equation}
S_{yU}^2=E(X)=E(E(X|s_a))\text{, }
\end{equation}
where $s_a$ is the sample obtained in the first phase.

We know that $E(S_{ys_a}^2)=S_{yU}^2$, so we just need and $X$ such that $E(X|s_a)=S_{ys_a}^2$.

The first phase sample $s_a$ is partitioned into $H_{s_a}$ strata $(s_{ah})_{h=1}^{H_{s_a}}$, so we can decompose $S_{ys_a}^2$ into it's "between" and "within" components, namely
\begin{equation}
S_{ys_a}^2=\sum_{h=1}^{H_{s_a}}\frac{n_{s_{ah}}-1}{n_{s_a}-1}S_{ys_{ah}}^2+\sum_{h=1}^{H_{s_a}}\frac{n_{s_{ah}}}{n_{s_a}-1}(\bar{y}_{s_{ah}}-\bar{y}_{s_a})^2\text{, }
\end{equation}
where $n_{s_a}$ is the size of the first phase sample $s_a$ and $n_{s_{ah}}$ is the number of elements of $s_a$ that live in the $h$-th stratum.

As far as I know, $S_{ys_h}^2$, where $s_h$ is the part of the second phase sample living in the $h$-th stratum, is an unbiased estimator of $S_{ys_{ah}}^2$ (given $s_a$), and it's easy to find unbiased estimators of $\bar{y}_{s_{ah}}$ and $\bar{y}_{s_a}$ too. Therefore, carefully substituting we obtain our desired unbiased $S_{yU}^2$ estimator
\begin{equation}
S_{ys_a}^2=\sum_{h=1}^{H_{s_a}}\frac{n_{s_{ah}}-1}{n_{s_a}-1}S_{ys_h}^2+\frac{n_{s_a}}{n_{s_a}-1}\sum_{h=1}^{H_{s_a}}w_{ah}(\bar{y}_{s_{h}}-\widehat{\bar{y}}_{U})^2\text{. }
\end{equation}

Don't worry about the last sum, as it matches the book's expression, however, according to the book, the coefficients multiplying the terms of the first sum should be
\begin{equation}
w_{ah}(1-\delta_h)\text{, }
\end{equation}
where $w_{ah}=\frac{n_{s_{ah}}}{n_{s_a}}$ and $\delta_h=\frac{1}{n_{s_h}}(\frac{n_{s_a}-n_{s_{ah}}}{n_{s_a}-1})$ and $n_h$ is the number of elements in the second phase sampling lying in the $h$-th stratum.

Any idea?